# dyn:evaluate() is not evaluating correctly?

Tags: php, xslt, xpath, exslt

For some reason, my XPath query is not working when executed inside the XSLT via dyn:evaluate(). I'm using PHP and `hasEXSLTSupport()` evaluates to `true`

Here's my raw XML document:

```
<getListValues>
    <node>
        <Assignee>Assignee Value</Assignee>
        <Summary>Summary Value</Summary>
        <Incident_Number>Incident_Number Value</Incident_Number>
    </node>
</getListValues>
```

I'm using this XPath statement:

```
//node[Assignee!=""]/*[name()="Summary" or name()="Incident_Number" or  name()="Assignee"]
```

And in my XSLT, I'm using this section to check if it worked:

```
<xsl:variable name="elementValue" select="dyn:evaluate($query)" />
<xsl:value-of select="$elementValue" />
```

Where `$query` evaluates to the string with the XPath expression (I know because I checked with `xsl:value-of` as well).

I'm not getting returned any errors. In fact, doing a `<xsl:value-of select="boolean($elementValue)" />` evaluates to `false`! This means it's not getting returned anything.

My stylesheet headers are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
```

It seems the XPath just isn't getting evaluated, even though it's perfectly valid (I checked with PHP and Notepad++'s XPatherizerNPP extension). What am I missing?

**EDIT**

My actual scripts are inside several classes and folders, so I'm posting a simpler version of what I'm running. It's equivalent in that dyn:evaluate() still doesn't work even though Notepad++ tells me it should, and that I've just copy-pasted functions in other classes into one for easier reference.

My **mock.xml** is the script I'm parsing

```
<getListValues>
<node>
    <Assignee>Assginee Value</Assignee>
    <Summary>Summary Value</Summary>
    <Incident_Number>Incident_Number Value</Incident_Number>
</node>
```

My `countFieldValues.xml` stylesheet calls on PHP to parse individual subtrees at a time in its readSubtree php function call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" extension-element-prefixes="dyn">

    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="nodeIterate" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="nodeIterate">
        <xsl:variable name="subtree" select="php:functionString('xsltMaster::readSubtree', $dataset)" />
        <xsl:if test="boolean($subtree)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$subtree"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="nodeIterate" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <br/>The current node: <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
        <br/>The query: <xsl:value-of select="$query" /><br/>
        <xsl:variable name="elementValue" select="dyn:evaluate($query)" />
        <br/>What dyn:evaluate() evaluates to: <xsl:value-of select="boolean($elementValue)" /><br/>
        <xsl:if test="boolean($elementValue)">
            <xsl:for-each select="$elementValue">
                <br/>What dyn:evaluate() evaluates to specifically: <xsl:value-of select="$elementValue" /><br/><br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!--<xsl:variable name="archivist" select="php:functionString('xsltMaster::storeCount', $element, $elementValue)" />-->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My `testscript.php` calls the class and executes everything

```
<?php

require_once "class.php";
$source = "countFieldValues.xml";

$query = '//node[Assignee!=""]/*[name()="Summary" or name()="Incident_Number" or  name()="Assignee"]';
$test4 = new xsltMaster;
$test4->createXSLT($source);

$test4->processDataSet($query, "mock.xml", "processedMock.json");
```

My **class.php** is the processor. It uses the XMLReader and XSLTProcessor classes in PHP.

```
<?php
class xsltMaster{

    protected static $_read;
    private $_xslt;
    protected $_dom;

    public function __construct(){
        // load DOM XML
        $this->_dom = new DOMDocument();
        $this->_dom->loadXML('<root />');
    }

    /*
        Creates the XSLT object on the currently loaded DOM document
        If the XSLT is already loaded, it will delete it
        It will then load the stylesheet
    */
    public function createXSLT($xsl){
        if(!empty($this->getXSLT())){
            $this->deleteXSLT();
        }
        $xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
        if(!$xsldoc->load($xsl)){
            throw new PDOException('Failed to open XML stylesheet!');
        }
        $this->getXSLT(new XSLTProcessor())->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
        unset($xsldoc);

        return true;
    }

    /*
        Getters/setters for the XSLT processor
    */
    protected function getXSLT($xslt=false){
        if(!empty($xslt)){
            $this->_xslt = $xslt;
        }
        return $this->_xslt;
    }


    // this will register PHP functions and run PHP XMLReader inside XSLT
    public function processDataSet($query, $source, $destination){
        // set-up
        $this->getXSLT()->registerPHPFunctions();
        $this->getXSLT()->setParameter('', 'query', $query);
        $this->getXSLT()->setParameter('', 'dataset', $source);
        $this->getXSLT()->setProfiling('profile9.txt');
        echo "has EXSLT support? ", var_dump($this->getXSLT()->hasEXSLTSupport()), "<br/>";

        // execute
        print $this->getXSLT()->transformToXML($this->_dom);
        #file_put_contents($destination, json_encode(self::$_countList));

        // clean up
        $this->getXSLT()->removeParameter('', 'dataset');
        $this->getXSLT()->removeParameter('', 'query');
    }

    public static function readSubtree($url=false){
        // check if reader has already been initialized
        if(empty(self::$_read)){
            // if reader has not been initialized, check if a url is supplied
            if(empty($url)) throw new PDOException("There is no file defined for transformation!");
            // create the reader
            self::$_read = new XMLReader;
            self::$_read->open($url);
            // loop until you reach the first node
            while (self::$_read->name !== 'node'){
                self::$_read->read();
            }
        } else {
            // if the logic gets here, the reader has already initialized
            // just move to the next node
            self::$_read->next();
        }
        // once you find the first subtree, return it
        // as long as we're still landing on a node element, return that expanded subtree
        if(self::$_read->name === 'node'){
            #echo "<pre>",var_dump(self::$_read->getReader()->expand()),"</pre>";
            return self::$_read->expand();
        }
        // if it gets here, then we're at the bottom of the file
        return null;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found some expressions for which `dyn:evaluate()` does return node-sets.
But they're a bit strange.

Here's when they evaluate to true:

```
Assignee
Summary
Incident Number
*[name()="Assignee"]
*[name()="Assignee" and text()="Assignee Value"]
```

But these evaluate to false:

```
*[Assignee="Assignee Value"]
//Assignee
```

What's the deal...?

**UPDATE:**

On Michael's suggestion, I ran his test and got this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <processor>libxslt</processor>
  <support>true</processor>
  <path>/root/bravo</path>
  <target/>
</results>
```

The failure part is the target is an empty element.

Comment: Why don't you post code that would enable us to reproduce your problem by running it **as is**? That would mean a complete, well-formed XML input, and an equally complete XSLT stylesheet. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: will do, editing now :)

Comment: I've even changed the query I'm using to `//Assignee` just to make it simple, but nothing happens. I still get an empty result.

Comment: Your mock.XML is still not a well-formed XML document (missing closing tag `</getListValues>`).

Comment: Yes -- sorry about that. I don't know why but that was just how it was rendered when I put the XML document in the code block. Will try to fix it.

Comment: hi Michael. Sorry, your solutions didn't really solve my issue so I can't accept it. I've instead used a workaround where I let my PHP do the work instead of XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try a much more simple test and report the results:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <alpha/>
    <bravo/>
    <charlie/>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" 
extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="path" select="'/root/charlie'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <processor>
            <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/> 
        </processor>
        <support>
            <xsl:value-of select="function-available('dyn:evaluate')"/>
        </support>
        <path>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path"/>
        </path> 
        <target>
            <xsl:copy-of select="dyn:evaluate($path)"/>
        </target>   
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Parameter**

```
path = "/root/bravo"
```

**Expected result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <processor>libxslt</processor>
  <support>true</support>
  <path>/root/bravo</path>
  <target>
    <bravo/>
  </target>
</results>
```

---

### 2.

**In response to your results:**

Either dyn:evaluate() doesn't work, despite the indications, or there's something wrong with the way you're passing the parameter. This could be determined by adding one more element to the tests:

```
<verify>
    <xsl:copy-of select="dyn:evaluate('/')"/>
</verify>
```

---

### 3.

**Please try again with this one:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" 
extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="path" select="'/root/charlie'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <processor>
            <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/> 
        </processor>
        <support>
            <xsl:value-of select="function-available('dyn:evaluate')"/>
        </support>
        <path>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path"/>
        </path> 
        <eval-param>
            <xsl:copy-of select="dyn:evaluate($path)"/>
        </eval-param>   
        <eval-string>
            <xsl:copy-of select="dyn:evaluate('/root/charlie')"/>
        </eval-string>  
        <copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/root/charlie"/>
        </copy> 
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please try again, with the updated version. -- P.S. Please do not add anything to the test.

Comment: Test failed still, updating my question with the result. The problem is just the target field is blank

Comment: but if I use `path = '/root'` or `path = "root"` it evaluates correctly. Soon as I add "bravo" though, it fails

Comment: I added in the verify tags you suggested and it returns empty. How could I fix this?

Comment: about your latest update, for `dyn:evaluate('/')` it evaluates to `<root/>`, but getting a child element, it returns null

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't add up. Based on your results, I would say that the input XML is not what I suggested.

Comment: that's too bad. but it is what you suggested. `file_get_contents("mock.xml")` shows the input is as expected

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is not XSLT. So you're not testing the same chain and the result is meaningless. Please try again with the updated version (#3) above.